# Looking for some help on how to create a toggle for showing and hiding an input in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a toggle for the only input you see inside of the span so I could hide it once I click the "Edit" button again. Any idea on how to make it work?

HTML:

```html
<h2>Universities</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <li>
    {{ item }}

    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-default"
      style="background-color: #ffe4b5"
      (click)="editIndex = i"
    >
      Edit
    </button>
    <span>
      <input *ngIf="editIndex === i" />
    </span>
    <span>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-default"
        style="background-color: #90ee90"
      >
        Save
      </button>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

TS:

```js
  items: string[] = [];
  editIndex: number | undefined;
  showInput: boolean = false;

  showData(index: any) {
    console.log(this.items[index]);
  }
```

(I created ShowData just to test if the index of the item works in the console when I click it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `editIndex` on click:

```html
<!-- component template -->

<button type="button" (click)="setEditIndex(i)" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #ffe4b5">
```

```js
// component

setEditIndex(index: number): void {
  if (this.editIndex === index) {
    this.editIndex = null;
  }
  else {
    this.editIndex = index;
  }
}
```

Your condition check in the template for `editIndex === i` should work after that.

Comment: It's not working sadly.

Comment: There's something else wrong in your code. Here's a working StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h8mxqk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you, now it works, but would it be possible to reset it clicking the same "Edit" button instead of creating a new one? May I also ask you the process behind your solution so I could learn from this if possible? Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated the StackBlitz so that clicking the same edit button clears the index. What would you like to know about the process?

Comment: I also updated the answer with the same logic from the StackBlitz

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the editIndex in the click function

In html

```
<button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-default"
      style="background-color: #ffe4b5"
      (click)="toggle()"
    >
      Edit
    </button>

<span>
      <input *ngIf="editIndex" />
    </span>
```

In .ts

```
editIndex = false;
toggle() {
 this.editIndex = !this.editIndex
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working sadly.

Comment: I have updated the code, just need to initialise editIndex as a boolean